# Im getting an Error icant resolve - Uncaught TypeError: _postSchema.Post is not a constructor

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, redux-form

I'm trying to get values from the form and save them to a local mongoDb, but I have an error. I would greatly appreciate any help to solve this problem.
I don't know if the problem is in the form definition, or maybe in the way babel interpret the code

My Schema
just another schema

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
const { Schema } = mongoose

const schemaPost = new Schema({ title: String, body: String })

export const Post = mongoose.model('post', schemaPost)
```

my Class
basic definition for a redux-form

```
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form'
import { Post } from './schemaPost'

class CreatePost extends Component {
  renderInput = ({ input, label }) => {
    return (
      <div>
        <label> {label} </label>
        <input {...input} />
      </div>
    )
  }

  onSubmit = values => {
    new Post({
      title: values.title,
      body: values.body
    }).save()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit(this.onSubmit)}>
          <Field name='title' component={this.renderInput} label='enter title' />
          <Field name='body' component={this.renderInput} label='enter body' />
          <button>Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default reduxForm({ form: 'createPost' })(CreatePost)
```

[image: the error]

Answer (score 0):

try changing from

```
export const Post = mongoose.model('post', schemaPost)
```

to

```
export const Post = mongoose.model('Post', schemaPost)
```

Comment: Check what is the error by:
model_name.save(function (err) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
});

Comment: i try that... it doesnt get to the .save() command, its failing in the constructor definition

Answer (score 0):

Do this to export

```
const Post = mongoose.model('post', schemaPost);
export { Post };
```

If you are exporting objects, this is the correct syntax for export

If you want to stick with your existing approach for exporting, you need to change your import & export statement like this

```
// export
export mongoose.model('post', schemaPost);

// import
import Post from './schemaPost';
```

Comment: i try that... basicly the same error

"Uncaught TypeError: _postSchema2.default is not a constructor"

Comment: Alright, try this one out for both import / export, updated the answer again